# drupal 7 comment moderation modules

Tags: 7, comments, users

I am looking for modules that can extend drupal 7 comment admin. 
For example, I want to be able to set different statues for comments, like Approved, pending, spam and unapproved.
And maybe comment moderation history, in comment admin it should show a log of who changes the text, who changes status of a comment. the only module i can find is for drupal 6.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the name of the module that you found?

Comment: i haven't found one.

Comment: Thought you said "the only module i can find is for drupal 6", was it comment_revisions one by any chance?

Comment: oh, this one. http://drupal.org/project/comment_moderation/

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/comment_workflow this one hasn't seen an update since D5 =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to "set different statuses for comments, like approved, pending, spam and unapproved" using [Flags](http://drupal.org/project/flag), which are D7 only.

I could not find anything that adds revisions to comments, or comments to flag changes.

The workflow module allows you to assign states to nodes, and comment each state change, but the comment_workflow module is available only for D5. Hopefully someone else might have better news.

Comment: installed antispam, but flags seems pretty nice too.

Comment: +1 for flag module. You can look for the [series of screencasts on NodeOne](http://nodeone.se/sv/node/703) for flag module.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you can combine Flags + Rules for setting rules like: "Whenever a comment is flagged as spam 3 or more times, remove it". I've actually implemented that functionality and it works. So you can in essence combine human- or community-driven spam control (Flags+Rules) in conjunction with machine control (Mollom, Akismet, antispam) for maximum efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what you are looking for is actually a D7 port of [Nodecomments](http://drupal.org/project/nodecomment) which is unavailable. This module effectively uses nodes for comments thereby giving you access to everything that is possible with a node such as revisioning and so on. While there is no D7 port of nodecomments yet, it might be worth taking [Advanced Forum](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) out for a test ride to see what features it supports as it integrates with nodecomments (amongst other things) in D6.

As amateur barista mentioned, the Flags module is currently your best (limited) bet for D7.

Answer (score 1):

This may not do everything you want but [Antispam](http://drupal.org/project/antispam) is useful as:

- It connects to Akismet, TypePad AntiSpam or Defensio
- Can use its own rules
- Holds spam in a queue
- Gives stats and even some pretty charts
- Notifications of spam

Comment: yeah i installed anti spam. it should be good.

Comment: Cool, I have been using the D6 version for about a year, what a relief to have intelligent spam handling.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best answer to this question is now [Workflow](https://drupal.org/project/workflow) module.

Since version 2.0, this module supports defining a workflow for any Entity type. This means you can define different workflows for Nodes (content types), comments and even users. Not only this module is multi-purpose which covers all entity types, but also it is a very flexible and powerful in defining different states, transitions, and permissions.

It also have great integration with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/Views) so you can query things like current entity state, time of last state change, the user who made the last state change, etc. etc. in Views.

Here is general steps to setup a workflow:

1. Install Workflow 2.x
2. Enable **Workflow Access** and **Workflow Field** submodules
3. Add a Workflow field to the entity type you want (comment in your case)
4. Define states for that entity type (e.g. `Approved`, `Pending`, `Spam`, `Unapproved`)
5. Specify which roles have which access permissions (view/edit/delete) at each state. (See the below figure)
6. For each role, define the permitted transitions between states (e.g. author can switch from Draft to Review state but cannot go back, while Editor can do both).  (See the last figure)

Note that [Workflow Fields](https://drupal.org/project/workflow_fields) is a different module which provides field-level permissions (e.g. making a field read-only or hidden in some states). So don't confuse **Workflow Field** submodule (which is integrated in Workflow) with the **Workflow Fields** module (which is a separate module developed for a different purpose).

## "Access" page:

(Open image in a new window and zoom for a better view)
[image: Access]

## "Transitions" page:

(Open image in a new window and zoom for a better view)
[image: Transitions]